# Spring Security disable method security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

While there are plenty of resources that point out how to disable Spring Security, there is not an explaination on how to disable method security.

One example:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
)
```

This however does not prevent the `MethodSecurityInterceptor` from kicking in, followed by a `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException`.

Is there a convenient way to disable method security without removing all annotations?

**Edit:**

Im talking of

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
```

followed by

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SOME_AUTHORITY')")
```

**Edit 2:**

As mentioned earlier, you simply cannot disable global method security by setting the parameters false:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of all global method 
configuration, no annotation support was actually activated
```

Comment: @WildDev See Edit 2, this does not work as mentioned earlier

Comment: @Glains: Did you try to remove the whole `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation?

Comment: @Glains, assume because of `SecurityAutoConfiguration.class` is excluded. Try with `@SpringBootApplication` without params

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that somewhere in the application a custom `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` has been created. That, of course, is responsible for the described problem above. After removing it (or moving it to a serarate profile), the problem disapeared.